# Get access_token from Web API, when you have token, idToken, etc, from Google

Tags: angular, asp.net-web-api, jwt, access-token, google-authentication

I used [angular-6-social-login](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-6-social-login) to signin with google in my website, as shown in the link. Now it return following data =>

```
email:"xxxxx"
id:"xxxxxxx"
idToken:"xxxx.xxxxxxxxx.xxxxxx"
image:"https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/xxxx/photo.jpg"
name:"Abhishek Jaiswal"
provider:"google"
token:"ya29.GlztBZpLW2v1jld20GR0iHOjMiveYmDhnaDRjWmsmh8tH_DSVW4-lRnYIL4Eau2-ZKVXlFFK-alCk5-REBR22aKkeUUIats14KtXEGfHlZIw5iIlKP5LSuEAtmnG0w"
```

I decoded that idToken as [JSON Web Token Decoder](https://www.jsonwebtoken.io/) on Web Api, cross-examined token(accessToken as provided by google) with "at_hash" value of idToken.
Now after that much of validation, I check for prior registration of user, and register him inside if block.

**Note:** I am doing these validations & registrations in manually. So, I am not using methods provided by Web ApiIdentity, like ExternalLogin, etc..

In case of normal logins, I issue a post request to `http://localhost:57310/token` with username, password, and grant_type, and that provides me accessToken, so it is authorized.

But, In this case, I am already on API, so no need for any post request, and I already have token(by google), but this one is not provided by web api, so not authorized.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this use case, I recommend you to use [ng-gapi](https://github.com/rubenCodeforges/ng-gapi). It will permit you to login with Google, retrieve credentials (JWT with identity), and request for an access_token to be used with Google API calls.

Behind the scene, it's a [Google Sign-in API](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/reference#gapiauth2authresponse) integration. So no worry about refreshing access_token for example, and also verifying JWT signature.

Comment: I guess, it is doing everything in angular only, but then I have to send user data to web api to store them in database. And while fetching profile, I send the access_token set during login that gets verified by web api and profile data is provided. SO, the access_token should be set at webapi, and this method will provide it from google to angular.

Comment: I solved the problem, and edited the question, that includes how I verified everything (for everyone). But your method is also useful. I just don't know how it related with web API token based authentication and data retrieval. So, don't delete this answer. And, have a look at updated problem.

Comment: Hi @AbhishekJaiswal are you able to get refresh token using social login??

Comment: Hi @Thierry Falvo if we use ng-gapi to get access token will it last for long? or it expires after 60min?

Comment: @eshwarchettri Yes, I was able to do that, but now the project is complete. And I did social login through Web API completely.

Comment: can you please send me the piece of code how you did that?

Comment: @eshwarchettri, ng-gapi is just a wrapper, and give you access to Google Sign-in API. Yes `access_token` will expire depending on Google rule (no link with ng-gapi here), but Google Sign-in will automatically refresh your token. Have a look [at doc here] (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/sign-in).